# How to use flexbox to make two columns of same width?

Tags: css, flexbox

I'm just starting my flexbox journey and have encountered the silliest problem: I can't figure out how to have two columns of equal width.

My markup looks like this:

```
<div class="flex-wrap">
  <div class="left-col"></div>
  <div class="right-col"></div>
</div>
```

and my css is

```
.flex-wrap {
  display: flex;
  flex: 2 1 auto;
}
```

They start out equal width, and responsively remain the same width UNTIL a certain point at which the content of left begins to push it larger.

How can I assure they stay the same width?

Comment: `flex:2 1 auto;` property is always given to children, not to the parent.

Answer (score 0):

Use flex properties like so.

```css
.flex-wrap {
  display: flex;
}

.flex-wrap div {
  flex: 1 0 50%;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-wrap">
  <div class="left-col">Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolores aliquid suscipit, id perferendis quos at assumenda repellat libero itaque obcaecati velit sunt asperiores non nisi.</div>
  <div class="right-col">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

you need to use
`max-width: 1010px; width: 100%;`